# How do I send a very simple status update with the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, http, post, twitter, status

I'm building an app that will allow the user to send a status update to twitter about something they have done in the app.

What is the easiest way to authenticate the user in the settings and have the app update their status when they tap a button?

Any help/ sample code is greatly appreciated.

-GVG
PHP/ iPhone SDK Developer
http://gilesvangruisen.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a lot of people use the source code from Matt Gemmell:

http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

That should be a good starting point.